# decision tree for visualisation using Graphviz? Displaying image file in jupyter lab?

Tags: pyspark, graphviz, jupyter-lab, graph-visualization

I am building decision tree for visualisation of obvious rules from data.

Using graphviz to visualise this graph using foloowing code:

```
from six import StringIO  
import pydotplus 
from sklearn import tree
dotfile = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(dt_default, out_file=dotfile) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue())
```

Till this point it works fine.
Now i am stuck on this step.

i tried

```
graph
```

output is

```
<pydotplus.graphviz.Dot object at 0x7fee800f6310>
```

i tried

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image(graph)
```

output is

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

i tried

```
plt = Image(graph.create_png())
display(plt)
```

output is

```
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

i tried

```
graph.create_png()
```

output is

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\t\x1c\x00\x00\x01\xf3\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\xc7G\xd4\xa5\x00\x00\x00\x06bKGD\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\xa0\xbd\xa7\x93\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xec\xddy\\\xcdy\xff\xff\xf1\xf7\xe9\xb4\'\x89\xc82\xd3\x90\xd0\xd8bd\xabQR\x91\xb1^\xa3\x0cc\x17c.\xcb\x95\xb1\x8f\xeb\xbahV2\x17jdf.\xcbD\xc2(K\xa6T\xa8(\xc6\x92\xa5d\xcb(\xc4\x18KZ\xb5P\x9d..............
```

Can someone help on next steps ? I am totally clueless whats happening ?

Comment: Have you tried: `graph_from_dot_data()` and then `graph.write_jpg()`?

Comment: i did try ```graph.write_jpg('Decision_Tree.jpg')``` but got error  ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Decision_Tree.jpg' ```

Comment: So you don't have permissions to write a file? That's a different issue.

Comment: Nope.. I can write datframe.. I tried  ```df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet('...path/dataf.parquet')``` and it worked...Issue is only with writing graphviz file...